# Navicat failed to connect to server over ssh tunnel on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ssh-tunnel, ubuntu-16.04, navicat

I'm trying to connect my database in my ec2 instance running on Ubuntu 16.04 with Navicat. But it keeps coming with **SSH: expected key exchange group packet from server**.

I have another instance running on Ubuntu 14.04, there I have an active connection with the same public key. I tried with MySQL Workbench and that is also working fine with both instances. So, it seems like Navicat is not working just only on the 16.04 instance.

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug of Navicat 11 with Ubuntu 16.04. Try to use another version of Navicat, even Navicat 9 should work well.

Comment: Could you explain any further? Any actions we could take to overcome the issue other than downgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a bug. Try to add this to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

Comment: hows does this solve the issue, please explain